# Cross server websockets

Tags: apache, http-headers, websocket

I get this error when I try to connect to my websocket server:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: origin mismatch: http://skerit.com != http://kipdola.be
```

Sure enough, I had to put in an origin response, like this:

```
    self.client.send("Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://kipdola.be\r\n")
    self.client.send("Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://kipdola.be:1234/\r\n")
```

But how do I set it to allow multiple origins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just echo back the origin the user provided in the request, the request looks somewhat like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: skerit.com
Origin: http://skerit.com
```

You perform a serverside check if the `Origin` header is in your list of allowed origins and just echo the origin back to the client:

```
self.client.send("Sec-WebSocket-Origin: " + headers["Origin"] + "\r\n")
```

Comment: I thought about doing it like that, does python get that information?

Comment: What HTTP library are you using? Websocket communication needs generation of the handshake data which partly comes through the headers. A list of headers should be available somewhere.

Comment: Just the socket library. Once a client accepts I just do a `server.accept()`, which gives me a pair (conn, address) (Info at http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.socket.accept )

Comment: Upon connection the client sends you a HTTP request, split it on `\r\n`. One of the lines should read `Origin: <host>`, that's the string you need. For the handshake you'll need to read out the `Sec-WebSocket-Key1`, `Sec-WebSocket-Key2` and the request body to calculate the data needed for handshake. I recommend you to read chapter six of http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-socket-protocol/

Comment: Oh right, of course, I forgot I received some data in the handshake part of the code. Thanks, it's working fine now.